# How to increase Width within a Div using JQuery - Newby

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make it when the users mouse enters the .container the #facial will slide to the left, pause for a second, and then increase it's width to fill the width of it's container.

Right now the #facial slides properly, but when i try to have #facial fill the entire width it pops out of it's container. Also i'd like it to pause for a moment to show the transition slower from when it enters the middle to when it increases it's width.

Here is my code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.container').mouseenter(function(){
        // When mouse enters the .container, #facial slides to center of .container.
        $('#facial').animate({right: '122px'});
        // #facial expands it's width to fit .container.
        $('#facial').width(400);
    }); 

});
```

[Here is my Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dshojaei/b008nczk/106/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to use percentages and to use absolute positioning.

https://jsfiddle.net/sy4pv8z3/

**Javascript:**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.container').mouseenter(function(){
       // When mouse enters the .container, #facial slides to center of .container.
       $('#facial').animate({right: '25%'})
                   .delay(500)
                   .animate({right: 0, width: '100%'});
    }); 
});
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color:#d6d6d6;   
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 200px auto;
    background-color:red;
    width:478px;
    height:200px;   
}
img {
    float:left;
    width:239px;
    height:200px;    
}
#facial {
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    width:239px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#008aaf;   
}
#facial h1, #facial h2 {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:30px;
    color:#FFFFFF;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.container').mouseenter(function() {
     // When mouse enters the .container, #facial slides to center of .container.
     $('#facial').animate({
       right: '122px',
       position: 'absolute'
     }).delay(500).animate({
       right: '0px',
       width: '478px'
     });
     // #facial expands it's width to fit .container.
     $('#facial').width(250); // .width(400) causes it to pop-out 
   });

 });
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #d6d6d6;
}
.container {
  margin: 200px auto;
  background-color: red;
  width: 478px;
  height: 200px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  width: 239px;
  height: 200px;
}
.image {
  position: absolute;
}
#facial {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 239px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #008aaf;
}
#facial h1,
#facial h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/enn2yyh7v/Facial.jpg" alt="Facial - Marketing Material" />
  </div>

  <div id="facial">
    <h1>Facial</h1>
    <h2>Marketing Material</h2> 
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Voted Answer: Double check the "absolut" on the Jquery side

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#facial').animate({right: '122px'}).delay(1000).animate({width: '400px'});
```